# Custom SearchableText and HTML fields in Plone

Tags: full-text-search, plone, zope, dexterity

I am writing a Dexterity content type which contains plain text and HTML fields. I want to have a custom SearchableText() method which exposes these fields to portal_catalog and Plone full text search.

I assume for plain text I can just do string join with spaces. But how I should preprocess HTML content when exposing it in SearchableText()?

Comment: I think the meta-question is "What does Archetypes do that Dexterity (CMF) base SearchableText() method does not yet?"  I would mimic whatever Archetypes does in your content class (use portal_transforms?).  I'm guessing there is an explicit decision not to rely upon CMF tools (like portal_transforms) in plone.dexterity.content.DexterityContent and subclasses).  This seems like a good opportunity to create an add-on base class to act as a bridge until Dexterity gets its own first-class transforms story.

Comment: For plain text, in addition to joining it with spaces, you need to make sure it is utf8-encoded, not unicode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

for converting data in plone there is a tool called portal_transforms, which is quite intelligent in converting stuff (depending on your os / installation it may also be able to convert .doc, .pdf etc.):

```
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName
transforms = getToolByName(self.context, 'portal_transforms')
stream = transforms.convertTo('text/plain', html, mimetype='text/html')
text = stream.getData().strip()
```

for indexing fields in dexterity I propose to use collective.dexteritytextindexer (but there is no TTW support at the moment).
-> http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.dexteritytextindexer
-> https://github.com/collective/collective.dexteritytextindexer

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [collective.dexteritytextindexer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.dexteritytextindexer) can help you to get part of what you want.